# Multiple package name for multiple apk

Tags: android, android-package-managers

We have an application that has same code but different Apk for different countries. What approach should I use to change package name dynamically?

Comment: Package name never change dynamically!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages

Comment: you can use the `applicationSuffixId` by configuring your build variants try to check it https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

Comment: use productFlavors  in your build.graddle

Answer (score 4):

In your build.gradle file add flavors

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        app1 {
            applicationId 'com.mobile.app1'
            versionCode 1
            versionName "0.9.4"
        }
        app2 {
            applicationId "com.mobile.app2"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "0.9.4"
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can create folders app1 and app2 in source folder.
Both folders app1 and app2 should have java and res folders inside, actually the same structure as main folder, but no files.

Only app1 and app2 specific files should be add into app1 and app2.
So, if you want different strings, you can add strings file into `app1/res/strings.xml` etc.
The same thing is for .java files, just have to add the same path as it's in main folder.

`main/java/com/.../MyClass.java` would be `app1/java/com/.../MyClass.java` and `app2/java/com/.../MyClass.java`

In the left down corner, you can switch build variant to run app in emulator or device.

When you're creating .apk or .aab, you'll have options to select which app you want build.

Answer (score 2):

Use productFlavors in gradle file.
you can find more details in [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id)

define multiple flavors and set the package name in each one like this:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
    }
    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationIdSuffix ".free"
        }
        pro {
            applicationIdSuffix ".pro"
        }
    }
}
```